# Como hacer un SELECT a un registro que tiene una fecha anterior?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Tengo una tabla `TipoCambio`

[image: Tabla TipoCambio]

De la cual quiero obtener el valor de un día anterior

Ejemplo:

```
Fecha 04/05/2023 Valor 18.12
Fecha 05/05/2023 Valor 19.12
```

A mi me interesa el valor de 18.12

¿Cómo puedo hacer la consulta sql?

Saludos y gracias

Comment: Imagino que 05/05/2023 es el día actual en tu sql correcto?

Comment: si, es correcto

Comment: Cuando dices un día anterior te refieres a: (1) El día anterior de un día dado, ej: 31-may si el día dado es 01-jun, sin importar si ese registro no exista. (2) El registro anterior al día dado, ej: 29-may si el día dado es 01-jun, pero no hubo registros en el 30, 31 de may.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour]. Tienes etiquetas [tag:mysql] y [tag:ms-access], pero los datos los tienes en un motor específico, ¿no es así? Sugiero que, de ser así, elimines la etiqueta que está de más, sobre todo con estos motores, ya que ambos suelen diferir bastante del estándar.

Comment: Si estas usando mysql puedes usar DATE_SUB te dejo un ejemplo a ver si te funciona http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/083da1/2/0

Comment: @JosueVargas gracias lo voy a probar

Answer (score 2):

Para obtener el registro que quieres, primero lo plantearé en lenguaje coloquial así:

Buscamos el registro anterior más próximo a una fecha dada, para obtener el tipo de cambio.

Para lograrlo, necesitamos ejecutar los siguientes pasos, en SQL.

- Preparar una consulta que nos devuelva registros de la tabla `TipoCambio` para  una moneda específica, por ejemplo `USD`, vamos a partir de ella y:
- Añadir a la cláusula where una condición para filtrar y obtener solo los días anteriores a la fecha de interés.
- Ordenar el resultado descendentemente por fecha
- Limitar el resultado del query a 1 fila que sería la única fila que contiene al día anterior más próximo a la fecha de interés.

Para obtener todo el registro, entonces, haríamos:

```
select top 1 TipoCambio.*
from TipoCambio
where TipoCambio.Moneda = 'USD'
  and (((TipoCambio.Fecha)<#5/5/2023#))
order by TipoCambio.Fecha desc;
```

Que nos devuelve:

[image: Grilla con resultado de la consulta en Access]

Mientras que, para obtener el valor puntual, sería de cambiar la cláusula select para obtener el campo `Valor`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 TipoCambio.Valor
FROM TipoCambio
WHERE TipoCambio.Moneda = 'USD'
  and (((TipoCambio.Fecha)<#5/5/2023#))
order by TipoCambio.Fecha desc;
```

Comment: Muy bien si me sirvió gracias, ahora me surgió otra duda... Sí la fecha dada es dinámica y diariamente se actualiza con nuevos registros, como podría ser???